# How to associate a Windows user with a linux user for samba share permissions

Tags: windows, network-shares, samba

I have a linux folder that I would like to share with a Windows machine. Currently using samba to set this [up](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-and-configure-samba-on-centos-7/). One problem with this is that there are ACLs (actually, [MapR volume controls](https://mapr.com/docs/60/SecurityGuide/Creating-Volume-Level-ACLs.html) (which are like HDFS ACLs)) on these directories that I don't see how could be applied to the samba share user on the Windows end (eg. the shared dir is for access by a certain group, but each member user has variying permissions on subfolders and files within that dir).

So my question is: is there any way to associate a Windows user to a linux user so that a samba share will recognize them from the Windows machine as having certain UID and GID values (for the purpose of correctly complying with the ACLs on the linux side)?

We currently have the linux machines linked to the Windows user accounts via SSSD (on the linux machines) connected to Active Directory (for the Windows machines) and this works for logging into both machines with the same login credentials, so wondering how I can get this to apply to the samba share underlying files?

Currently getting "no access permission" error (even though, ostensibly, the Windows users linux uid and gid in AD should pass the shares ACL restrictions). Anyone with more experience with these kinds of problems have any advice or best practices recommendations?

Comment: @Ramhound So are you saying that I need to make individual samba users (via `smbpasswd -a <user>`) for each of the users? Really have never used Samba before. In mean time (for others finding this question), looking into this (https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/windows_integration_guide/smb-sssd) which looks like what I may need.

Comment: I want to be clear. The problem is my lack of knowledge with your backend.  There is nothing specifically wrong with your question.  I am just allowing somebody else to help you since.